# KeyError: 'SECRET KEY'

Tags: python, json, dictionary, key, config

I am trying to access a secret key from a settings.py file through a config dictionary.
I don't think it's a syntax issue, but maybe I'm wrong

`settings.py` file:

```
with open('/etc/config.json') as config_file:
        config = json.load(config_file)
SECRET_KEY  = config['SECRET_KEY']
```

`config.json` file

```
{      
        "SECRET KEY": "-------"
}
```

I'm getting this error message `KeyError: "SECRET_KEY"`

Comment: `SECRET_KEY  = config['SECRET KEY']`

Comment: yep, ^, you are looking for `SECRET_KEY` but the file has `SECRET KEY`. Not the space vs. `_`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define the key as `SECRET KEY`, and then attempt to read it as `SECRET_KEY`. Those are not the same string (one contains an underscore and the other contains a space), so the attempt to read the string from the dictionary produces an error.